# Is it possible to write a Windows console application using PHP?

Tags: php, console-application

I'm going to build a big library for my PHP website.

Comment: [PHP: Command line usage](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Simple Example :

```
<?php
echo $argc."\n";
print_r($argv);
?>
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: @Nam Gi VU I don't know but maybe when php was installed.
I installed PHP by APM installer...

Comment: Remember to add the php bin path to your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, yes, it is possible to write a windows console application using PHP. Or any other language, for that matter.

However, if you want to "build a big library", I suggest instead writing a useful set of libraries.  In that case, I would consider the "windows console application" as a test runner, to execute your tests that ensure that your "big library" works as intended.